# React propTypes for 'system-provided' props

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

What is best practice for PropTypes when it comes to props provided by some React components, for example:

- props.location and props.match provider by ReactRouter
- props.dispatch() in case of component 'connected' to Redux store

Is it necessary to use propTypes for these properties or not?

In case of props.match, how deep should I check for property?
Is it enough to check for props.match or should I check for props.match.url if match.url is all I need in particular component?

Thank you

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class ProductsList extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
  }

  handleSelect(product_id) {
      this.props.dispatch(handleAddProduct(product_id));
  }

  render() {
      const {match, location} = this.props;

     return (... JSX code goes here ....)
  }
}

ProductsList.propTypes = {
  match: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  location: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default connect()(ProductsList)
```

Answer (score 0):

No. library itself use the propTypes. Check [this](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/Route.js) link

```
  Route.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.node]),
    component: PropTypes.func,
    exact: PropTypes.bool,
    location: PropTypes.object,
    path: PropTypes.string,
    render: PropTypes.func,
    sensitive: PropTypes.bool,
    strict: PropTypes.bool
};
```